# Process which can be closed by it's own only

Tags: c#, process

I really want to understand how to antiviruses works, I readed some articles about that. The first thing I was wondering is if this possible to create a process (application of course) which can be closed by itself only? In C# of course.

For example antiviruses works in some strange mode that even system administrator cannot close them from task manager or using simple `Kill()` method because access to these processes is denied.

I am curious if is there a way to create a console application which will be work in this "strange mode"  and can be killed only by special command. Any attempt to close this app in task manager or X button should throw error that "Access denied".

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have deep knowledge on that topic, but I believe antiviruses have a driver (in kernel space) that hooks termination requests and prevents them. You may want to search for "kernel mode hook". ICBWT.

Comment: As Cicada says, typically protected programs are run as Kernel Mode programs (not sure if a windows app can be protected the same way); to start, look into ObRegisterCallbacks http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558692.aspx and ObReleaseObjectSecurity  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558695%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: [Interesting read](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx)